# Can't pass value between two components in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

So I am following Academind tutorial on youtube on react native but i can't seem to get to work the passing of values between tow components.
In startgamescreen on this line    `onPress={()=>props.onGame(selNumber)}`       I seem to follow him and pass selNumber but the error I get is onGame is not a function and undefined 
and in App.js

```
const gameHandler=(selNum)=>{
    setUserNumber(selNum);
};


let content=<StartGameScreen onGame={gameHandler} />;
```

Here I seem to exactly follow him and pass the gamehandler but I still don't get what went wrong. Please help me I have tried to debug this code for a while now.

`StartGameScreen.js`

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Alert ,Text, Button, TouchableWithoutFeedback,Keyboard} from 'react-native';
import NumberComponents from '../components/NumberComponent';
import Card from '../components/Card';
import Colors from '../constants/colors';
import Input from '../components/Input';

const StartGameScreen = props => {
   const [enteredValue,setEnteredValue]=useState('');
   const [confirmed,setConfirmed]=useState(false);
   const [selNumber,setSelNumber]=useState('');
   const numberHandler =textinput=>{
      setEnteredValue(textinput.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));
   };

   let confirmedOutput;
   if(confirmed){
      confirmedOutput=<Card style={styles.confirm}>
         <Text>You Selected:</Text>   
         <NumberComponents children={selNumber}/>  
         <Button title='Start Game' onPress={()=>props.onGame(selNumber)}/>                    
      </Card>
   }

   const resetInputHandler=()=>{
      setEnteredValue('');
      setConfirmed(false);
   };
   const confirmButtonHandler=()=>{
      const chosenNum=parseInt(enteredValue);
      if(isNaN(chosenNum)  || chosenNum<=0 || chosenNum>99){
         Alert.alert(
            'InValid Number',
            'Please Enter Valid Number Between 1 and 99',
            [{text:'Okay',style:'destructive',onPress:resetInputHandler}]
         )
         return;
      }
      setConfirmed(true);
      setEnteredValue('');
      setSelNumber(chosenNum);
      Keyboard.dismiss();
   };
   return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>{Keyboard.dismiss();}}>
      <View style={styles.screen}>
         <Text style={styles.title}> Start A New Game </Text>
         <Card style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'green', fontSize: 15 }}>Choose A Number</Text>
            <Input 
               keyboardType='number-pad' 
               maxLength={2} 
               style={styles.input} 
               blurOnSubmit
               onChangeText={numberHandler}
               value={enteredValue} 
            />
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
               <View style={styles.button}>
                  <Button 
                     title='Reset'
                     color={Colors.accent}
                     onPress={resetInputHandler} />
               </View>
               <View style={styles.button}>
                  <Button 
                     title='Confirm'
                     onPress={confirmButtonHandler}
                     color='orange' />
               </View>
            </View>
         </Card>
         {confirmedOutput}
      </View>
   </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);
};
```

in App.js

```
import React,{ useState }  from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import Header from './components/Header';
import StartGameScreen from './screens/StartGameScreen';
import GameScreen from './screens/StartGameScreen';




export default function App() {
  const [userNumber,setUserNumber]=useState();

const gameHandler=(selNum)=>{
    setUserNumber(selNum);
  };


  let content=<StartGameScreen onGame={gameHandler} />;

  if(userNumber){
    content=<GameScreen userChoice={userNumber}/>;
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Header title="Guess A Number"/>     
       {content}      
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen:{
    flex:1,    
  }
});
```

Comment: the code looks OK on a quick view. have you tried to delete as much code as possible to create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that will still reproduce the problem?

Comment: No the problem was in the imports, I am an idiot I was so lost in debugging this that I didn't see that i had imported StartGameScreen twice therefore it didn't work...sorry I am a beginner..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add onGame={gameHandler} into this component:

```
if (userNumber) {
  content = <GameScreen onGame={gameHandler} userChoice={userNumber} />;
}
```

Since GameScreen and StartGameScreen are the same components,

```
import StartGameScreen from './screens/StartGameScreen';
import GameScreen from './screens/StartGameScreen';
```

in the second case when userNumber is not false the GameScreen component was called without the onGame props.

See the working stripped down version in codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-wright-3bccd

Comment: hello ,thanks for this I am an idiot and didn't import GameScreen instead imported startgamescreen twice which didn't therefore work, thank you very much....

Answer (score -2):

Hello if there are not parent-child relation between your components,you can use Event like DeviceEventEmitter.

Here is a good link for example: [https://callstack.com/blog/sending-events-to-javascript-from-your-native-module-in-react-native/][1]